# Can't find the missing key for the child

Tags: reactjs, sanity

novice developer here.

I can't seem to solve this missing key error. I've used the key prop for each time i've mapped but I can't seem to find the child with the missing key. please help!

I've tried putting key props in some of the child divs but still no success.

```
      <h2 className="head-text">Skills & Experience</h2>

      <div className="app__skills-container">
        <motion.div className="app__skills-list">
          {skills.map((skill) => (
            <motion.div
              whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
              className="app__skills-item app__flex"
              key={skill.name}
            >
              <div
                className="app__flex"
                style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}
              >
                <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name}/>
              </div>
              <p className="p-text">{skill.name}</p>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="app__skills-exp">
          {experience.map((experience) => (
            <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-item" key={experience.year}>
              <div className="app__skills-exp-year">
                <p className="bold-text">{experience.year}</p>
              </div>
              <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works">
                {experience.works.map((work) => (
                  <>
                    <motion.div
                      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
                      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                      className="app__skills-exp-work"
                      data-tip
                      data-for={work.name}
                      key={work.name}
                    >
                      <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
                      <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
                    </motion.div>
                    <ReactTooltip
                      id={work.name}
                      effect="solid"
                      arrowColor="#fff"
                      className="skills-tooltip"
                    >
                      {work.desc}
                    </ReactTooltip>
                  </>
                ))}
              </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppWrap(
  MotionWrap(Skills, 'app__skills'), 
  'skills', "app__whitebg"
  );
```

Comment: Did you try changing the `<>` and `</>` to divs or sections and add a key to it? also, if you are looking for an easy way to implement keys you can do it this way: `list.map((item, key) => ( <div key={key}>{item.content}</div> )`. hope it helps

Comment: changing the <> and </> to a div with a key worked! thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Error is with `<>...</>` items in your

```
{experience.works.map((work) => (
  <>
    <motion.div key={work.name}>
      {/* ... */}
    </motion.div>
  </>
))}
```

They are top-level DOM nodes inside of your map function, so they should have the `key`, not the child `motion.div`.

But they cant have `key`, so you will need to use `Fragments`. They are just the same.

```
import {Fragment} from "react";

{experience.works.map((work) => (
  <Fragment key={work.name}>
    <motion.div
      whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      className="app__skills-exp-work"
      data-tip
      data-for={work.name}
    >
      <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
      <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
    </motion.div>
    <ReactTooltip
      id={work.name}
      effect="solid"
      arrowColor="#fff"
      className="skills-tooltip"
    >
      {work.desc}
    </ReactTooltip>
  </Fragment>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), the key has to be

> a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings

It is possible that the key you have provided for each element is not unique. For eg  `key={skill.name}` `key={experience.year}` will not work if there are two list items with the same `name` or `year` respectively.

What you can do is use any uniquely identifiable property of the list item or the index of the array.

```
 {skills.map((skill, index) => (
            <motion.div
              whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
              transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
              className="app__skills-item app__flex"
              key={index}
            >
              <div
                className="app__flex"
                style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}
              >
                <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name}/>
              </div>
              <p className="p-text">{skill.name}</p>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
```